# apache solr as a service hosting

Tags: apache, search, solr, hosting, saas

are you aware of the best companies which provide apache solr AS A SERVICE? where i can simply upload (or edit via some web control panel) my index and config files for SOLR and simply start using it

i do not want to be breaking my head with any sort of server administration on tomcat

just update my index and config files... tell solr where to look for data to index (via data import handlers) and thats it just start using it

any sort of load balancing / mirrors would be like icing on the cake

price does not matter as its for mission critical apps

please do not suggest me to boot up my own servers on amazon or rackspace or xyz and then deploy solr on them and manage all the administration - because thats what i want to avoid in the first place completely

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hosted full text search solutions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168634/hosted-full-text-search-solutions)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I wanted to update this post from 2011 now that it's 2017!   Today for folks looking for pure self service and simple Solr search we continue to recommend [www.websolr.com](http://www.websolr.com).  If you are looking for a managed complete Solr instances + some nice search analytics capability, then we've used [SearchStax](https://www.searchstax.com) very successfully.

Answer (score 5):

there is also this one:
http://www.opensolr.com/

> ***Opensolr*** proposes 3 types of Solr instances :
>
> - CMS instances (WordPress, Drupal, Joomla, eZ Publish, Typo3)
> - API instance (RESTful Web service) with fully customizable configuration files
> - Web sites Crawler instances

There is a free account (i think it can be used actually only for test the platform), and the price for the other kind of account is cheap (4$/8$ a month for medium accounts)

(i didn't try it yet, but it seems promising)

Answer (score 3):

If you use Drupal, there is also Midwestern Mac's [Hosted Apache Solr service](http://hostedapachesolr.com/), which works with Drupal 6 and 7, and all the different Solr integration modules. (Disclaimer: I'm the owner of Midwestern Mac—let me know what you'd like to see and I'll try to make it happen!).

Answer (score 2):

You can try contacting [Lucidworks](http://www.lucidimagination.com/About/Contact) with that question.

I heard they were working with Boomi on PaaS/Saas for their Lucidworks 1.4.
Although Boomi [don't explicitly say](http://www.boomi.com/products/evaluate/supported_applications) that they support Solr, this [webinar](http://www.lucidimagination.com/blog/2010/02/11/webinar-how-search-unlocks-log-metadata-to-visualize-your-business-process-in-the-cloud/) may suggest they were working with Lucidworks to include their Solr-based search engine in their portfolio.
Even if Lucidworks people don't provide SaaS, they're surely the right address to ask who does.

Good luck in your search and please get back to us with the information you manage to find...

**EDIT 04/2012:** 
If I had to make that choice today, I'd seriously consider [CloudBees](http://www.cloudbees.com) (which has [WebSolr](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/Websolr) plugin). It's a complete ALM & CI cloud framework for JVM-based languages, with loads of partner plugins (Jenkins, NewRelic, Sonar, MongoHQ, Cloudant, ...), many of them with free base options.
The most significant difference, when comparing with other SaaS/PaaS services, is that you can set up development environment and even deploy your app (on one node, of course) without even leaving your credit card details.

Comment: thanks mate... im trying with websolr.com at the moment... looks okay for small setups but they also offer dedicated instances with a lot more flexibility but ofcourse that costs a lot more (500 usd per month)

Comment: I just bumped into this: http://www.wijiti.com/contact/solr, an Australian company that's about to start offering Solr SaaS.

Answer (score 2):

The company IndexDepot ([www.indexdepot.com](http://www.indexdepot.com)) offers a hosted Solr service. It's easy to use, because you log into an web interface to edit your configuration files. Special configurations fitting your requirements are negotiable, e. g. dedicated master/slave Solr servers.

Comment: This is no longer available it seems

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand horizons.

> please do not suggest me to boot up my own servers on amazon or rackspace or xyz and then deploy solr

You can go with ready to use:
[http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/).
**Cloudsearch** provides simple API.

And more and more hosted **Elastic Search** solutions appears recently. I think it's because of cloud ES nature (easy to maintain search cloud).
[http://indexisto.com](http://indexisto.com/)
[http://qbox.io](http://qbox.io/)
But of course this is the matter of how sticky are you with **SOLR**.

Answer (score 2):

These guys also so hosted Solr.
https://www.hosted-solr.com/?locale=en

They also have a custom extension that integrates Solr into TYPO3 CMS.
http://www.typo3-solr.com/en/home/

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at our [Fully Managed Solr Cloud Hosting](https://www.searchstax.com/cloud-search-service/solr/), where we enable customers like you to not worry about managing and maintaining Solr infrastructure, but instead focus on building your application.

We offer shared clusters that caters to price conscious customers and dedicated nodes and dedicated clusters with white glove service for companies who want to completely offload search infrastructure and management.

We are a technology partner with AWS and depending upon the critical needs, can customize a hosted solr solution per our customers needs.

Answer (score 0):

```
please do not suggest me to boot up my own servers on amazon or rackspace or xyz 
and then deploy solr
```

You can try the below solr service provider, looks cheaper as well
http://indiasolr.com/