# Django haystack search engine with lowest memory usage?

Tags: django, memory, solr, web-hosting, django-haystack

I'm using webfaction as a host and they only give me 80mb of memory.  I originally wanted to use Solr to do a real time search index but it uses at least 50mb to run and more I'm guessing when I actually do stuff.  Plus running the website takes the rest of the memory.

Anyhow, I guess I'll have to settle for a queue index.  So what are the search engines for haystack in terms of memory usage from lowest to highest?

Which of the lower ends would you recommend using(speed is important)?

Perhaps another webhost would suit me better, if you can think of a better one, please tell me!

Thanks!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With so little memory I doubt you can do much with any search engine. I'd get another host or look into externally [hosted search engine solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168634/hosted-full-text-search-solutions-closed).